# Searching a list of cities

Tags: iphone, ios, database, uitableview

Could anyone give me a point in the right direction on how I should do this:

[image]

This sample from the Weather Channel shows what I would like to do. I just want to have a Table View in which someone could search for a city. I'm not sure where to get those resources and how to do it.

Comment: Look into the UISearchDisplayController. It's actually a tableview they have reading from a list of cities. :) Link to apple's documentation: [UISearchDisplayController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Oh, and if I'm not mistaken you're running the iOS 6 beta I see. (Nav bar gives it away.)

Comment: @ipwnstuff Oooops! Edited the image thanks :P and would you by any chance know what source they're using?

Comment: I have no idea but @Greg Wang added a list.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the World City List from [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities).

Is it the resource you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Create table view and search bar. You have to implement their delegates `UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate`.

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar1
{

    searchBar.showsSearchResultsButton = YES;
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    // flush the previous search content
    //Implement some code
 }
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar1
{

     searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    searchBar.showsSearchResultsButton = NO;
}
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    if([searchText isEqualToString:@""]||searchText==nil){
        [yourTable reloadData];
        return;
    }
    NSInteger counter = 0;
    for(NSString *name in yourArray)
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
        NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
      //  NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText];
      //  NSRange r = [name  ];
        if(r.location != NSNotFound)
        {
           //Implement the code.
        }
        counter++;
        [pool release];
    }
    [yourTable reloadData];
}
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar1
{

    // if a valid search was entered but the user wanted to cancel, bring back the main list content
    // Implement some code
    @try{
        [yourTable reloadData];
    }
    @catch(NSException *e){
    }
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    searchBar.text = @"";
}
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar1
{

    [searchBar1 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I have give to you incomplete methods and you can implement what you want to do.

I think it will be helpful to you.